# How to extract numbers and their indices from a string in Python

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm trying to write a function that will take a string and return a dictionary containing all of the numbers contained within the string and the index at which they begin.

For example the string `"1this is a 134 test15"` would produce the dictionary `{ 0:1, 11:134, 19:15 }`

I've seen solutions to many similar problems that make use of regular expressions, which work very well for extracting the numbers themselves but I have not been able to find a way to associate those numbers with the index they occur at.

Is it possible to use regular expressions to extract this kind of information from strings or is there a different way to do it that would be more suited to this kind of application.

Answer (score 7):

```
In [44]: strs="1this is a 134 test15"

In [45]: {m.start(0):int(m.group(0)) for m in re.finditer("\d+", strs)}
Out[45]: {0: 1, 11: 134, 19: 15}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "1this is a 134 test15"
>>> d = dict((m.start(), int(m.group())) for m in re.finditer(r'\d+', text))
>>> d
{0: 1, 19: 15, 11: 134}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`start()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.start) method of regular expression `MatchObject`s will provide the string offset of the current match.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a function, i hope this may be useful. There's surely an easier way to do it. Howerver, this is what I've worked out. I tried my best :)

```
def function(string,dic={},p=0):

   if len(string)==0:
      return dic

   else:
      i=0
      if string[0] in '1234567890':
        while string[i] in '0123456789':
          i+=1
          p+=1
        dic[p-len(string[:1])]=int(string[:i])
        string=string[i:]
        return function(string,dic,p)
      else: 
        p+=1
        return function(string[1:],dic,p)
```