# Python Regex Search string for all substrings having one or more numbers

Tags: python, regex, string, numbers, substring

In python, I have the following string:

`"fish 14~ reel 14 rod B14"`

I want to use REGEX to run through a for loop and return the location of each substring having one or more numbers in it. Ex.:

```
 For ():
     print location of substring
```

My expect output would be:

```
5
14
21
```

Please help, thanks.

ANSWER:
Ok I tested all of the following and they all work. So which one is fastest? Drum roll.... In order from fastest to slowest:
1) Perreal - 9.7ms
2) Jon - 10.5ms 
3) m.buettner - 12.3ms
4) upasana - 25.6ms

Thanks to all of you Python geniuses. There was another solution but I didn't test it. For various other reasons I chose Jon's method for my program.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extract numbers and their indices from a string in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16048548/how-to-extract-numbers-and-their-indices-from-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
s =  "fish 14~ reel 14 rod B14"

import re

words = re.finditer('\S+', s)
has_digits = re.compile(r'\d').search
print [word.start() for word in words if has_digits(word.group())]
# [5, 14, 21]
```

So, effectively find the indices of starts of words, then check each word to see if it's got digits in it...

If indeed the last entry should be 22 instead of 21, then you already have your answer in the possible duplicate...

Comment: Couldn't you do it in a single regex? Something like `\S*\d\S*`?

Comment: m.buettner, how would I go about doing what you propose? I think your solution is best because it is likely fastest (though I appreciate the other solutions). Jon, I want to avoid checking every word because I suspect it will take too long.

Comment: @user2104778 try using my pattern in Jon's `finditer` line, removing the `has_digits` line and removing the `if` part.

Comment: @user2104778 I think you'll find the speed difference over readability is going to be absolutely negligible

Comment: i don't understand either solution so readability is of no concern, lol. The reason I am concerned about speed is the fact that the actual strings I am reviewing are in the ten thousands of words in terms of length.

Comment: @user2104778 That's a new question... also I'm mobile at the moment so impractical for me to answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import re

s =  "fish 14~ reel 14 rod B14" 

p = re.compile('[0-9]+')

a = p.findall(s)

print a
```

for getting the position

```
for m in re.finditer(r'([a-zA-Z]+)?[0-9]+', s):
    st, en = m.span() 
    print "position ", st, en, " string ", s[st:en]
```

You should see

position  5 7  string  14
position  14 16  string  14
position  21 24  string  B14

which is correct!

Comment: I think the OP doesn't want to find the numbers, but the beginning of words that contain numbers (in particular, the position of `B` in `B21` and not the position of the `2`.

Comment: I can't try it out right now, but won't that still give you `22` for the last match?

Comment: Python position starts from 0.  You get the correct answer when you   say   print s[22:24]  gives 14 (the last two characters.  Correctly.

Comment: That is my point. He wants the position of `B` not of `1` in `B14`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this without using regex:

```
p = list()
for i in [ i for i,c in enumerate(str) if c.isdigit() ]:
    if len(p) == 0 or p[-1] + 1 != i:
        p.append(i)
print p
```

But this will give you the start position of digits that are not immediately preceded by another digit. Bending backwards to make this complete:

```
p = list()
for i in [ i for i,c in enumerate(str) if c.isdigit() ]:
    if i > 0 and not str[i - 1].isdigit():
        while i > 0 and str[i - 1].isalnum():
            i -= 1
        p.append(i)
print p
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re

str = "fish 14~ reel 14 rod B14"
index = 0
for x in str.split(" "):
    if re.search('\d', x):
        print(max(str.find(x), index))
    index += len(x) + 1
```

**output:**

```
5
14
21
```